# Memory Mapped I/O: Control Registers in I/O space vs Memory Space

Tags: memory, operating-system

In my book it mentions:

> The control registers of a device controller can be part of the memory itself or they can be part of a separate I/O space. If it is memory space, the memory responds to the request. If it is I/O space, the I/O device responds to the request.

The last sentence where it says `If it is I/O space, the I/O device responds to the request.` Why is it that when the control registers are in the memory space the I/O device is not involved at all? How does the data come from the device to the memory then if the I/O device is not involved and only the memory responds to the request.

I thought the I/O space is just a separate space in memory that is not associated with the kernel memory correct? So when it says that the I/O device will respond to the request if the controller registers are in the I/O space, does this mean that when the controller registers are in the memory space, then the device will not respond and somehow the data will already be in memory?

Comment: If you think my answer below is not not sufficient, please tell me what is missing. If it is OK, please mark the question as answered, so that it is closed.

Comment: Just marked it. Forgot sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the confusion comes from imprecise wording. I see it the following way:

A CPU uses either the same instructions to access memory and I/O registers („memory mapped I/O“), or „normal“ instructions to access memory, and special I/O instructions to access I/O registers („port mapped I/O“).
Usually a virtual address of the CPU is mapped to any other physical address by a memory management device.

Using memory mapped I/O, the single physical address space is typically filled with the main memory starting at address 0. The top address of the main memory depends on its size, but is typically much smaller than the top of the address space.
Say, you have a 64 bit address space, a 16 GB main memory would occupy the bottom addresses from hex 0x0000000000000000 to hex 0x0000000400000000, and the top addresses would not be used by the memory.
Thus they can be used to access device registers, that usually start at the top of the address space hex 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, and use the addresses below.
So, with memory mapped I/O, the main memory and the I/O devices simply look at the physical address on the address bus, and respond if the address matches their own addresses.

But one can also use different address spaces. Some computers, e.g. PDP11/45, used separate address spaces for instructions and data, that were distinguished by a special bit on the address bus, and others use separate address spaces for memory and I/O devices.
In the latter case, this is port mapped I/O. So, with port mapped I/O, the main memory responds only to addresses if the memory address space is addressed, and the I/O devices respond only to addresses if the I/O address space is addressed. Both cases are distinguished by a separate bit on the address bus.

More information can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O).